# How to perform replace all 'addr bytea' with 'addr_id bigint' in Postgre?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm currently trying to change a column's type from bytea to biting but it says ERROR:  cannot cast type bytea to bigint.

In the documentation of the application: https://github.com/algorand/indexer/blob/e45af391c687aef4a918ced569f5d8edcee5e24b/idb/postgres/internal/schema/setup_postgres.sql

It says replace all 'addr bytea' with 'addr_id bigint' and a mapping table?

How do I get this right?

Comment: You'd have to tell us what algorithm you want to use to calculate a `bigint` from a `bytea`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.